# SOSL not returning any result in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, knowledge

**Test Class**

```
    static testMethod void testBehavior() {
        User objUser = [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT 1];
        System.runAs(objUser) {
            String strContactId = String.valueOf([SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1].Id);
            Knowledge__kav objKav = new Knowledge__kav(Title = 'TestTitle', UrlName = 'TestTitle');
            insert objKav;
            knowledge__kav objKav2 = [SELECT Id,Title,KnowledgeArticleId FROM knowledge__kav WHERE Id =: objKav.Id];
            KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(objKav2.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
            Test.startTest();
            CaseCreationLightingController_ACE.createCase(strContactId, 'New', 'Phone', 'TestTitle');
            CaseCreationLightingController_ACE.fetchKnowledgeArticles(new List<String>{
                    'TestTitle'
            });
            Test.stopTest();
            Case objCase = [SELECT Id, Status, Origin FROM Case LIMIT 1];
            CaseComment objCaseComment = [SELECT Id, CommentBody, ParentId FROM CaseComment LIMIT 1];
            System.assertEquals(objCase.Id, objCaseComment.ParentId);
            System.assertEquals('New', objCase.Status);
            System.assertEquals('Phone', objCase.Origin);
        }
    }
```

**Method called**

```
    public static List<KnowledgeArticleWrapper_ACE> fetchKnowledgeArticles(List<String> lstComments) {
        List<KnowledgeArticleWrapper_ACE> lstArticleWrapper = new List<KnowledgeArticleWrapper_ACE>();
        List<String> lstErrors = new List<String>();
        // Generating a dynamic "OR" string which needs to be passed as a search parameter to the SOSL
        try {
            String strSearchTerms = '';
            for (String strComment : lstComments) {
                if (!String.isEmpty(strComment)) {
                    strSearchTerms += '("' + strComment + '")';
                }
                if (!String.isEmpty(strComment)) {
                    if (!String.isEmpty(strSearchTerms)) {
                        strSearchTerms += ' OR ';
                    }
                }
            }
            // Doing this to remove the trailing OR.
            if (strSearchTerms.endsWith(' OR ')) {
                strSearchTerms = strSearchTerms.removeEnd(' OR ');
            }
            Search.SearchResults objSearchResults = null;
            List<Search.SearchResult> lstSearchResults = new List<Search.SearchResult>();
            if (!String.isEmpty(strSearchTerms)) {
                objSearchResults = Search.find('FIND :strSearchTerms IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion(Id, Title, UrlName' +
                        ' WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 3)');
                lstSearchResults = objSearchResults.get('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
            }
            // Create the wrapper only if data is found else just add 'No articles found' and return it back.
            if (!lstSearchResults.isEmpty()) {
                for (Search.SearchResult searchResult : lstSearchResults) {
                    KnowledgeArticleVersion objArticleVersion = (KnowledgeArticleVersion) searchResult.getSObject();
                    lstArticleWrapper.add(new KnowledgeArticleWrapper_ACE(String.valueOf(objArticleVersion.Id), objArticleVersion.Title, null, lstErrors));
                }
            } else {
                lstArticleWrapper.add(new KnowledgeArticleWrapper_ACE(null, 'No articles found', null, lstErrors));
            }
        } catch (Exception objException) {
            List<ErrorLog_CF__c> lstErrorLog = ErrorLogClass_CF.processExceptionAndReturnErrorLog(objException);
            String name = [SELECT Name FROM ErrorLog_CF__c WHERE Id = :lstErrorLog[0].Id].Name;
            lstErrors.add(name);
            lstArticleWrapper.add(new KnowledgeArticleWrapper_ACE(null, null, null, lstErrors));
        }
        return lstArticleWrapper;
    }
```

But when I put a debug statement in my class :

```
        if (!String.isEmpty(strSearchTerms)) {
            System.debug([SELECT Id, UrlName, PublishStatus FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion]);
            objSearchResults = Search.find('FIND :strSearchTerms IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion(Id, Title, UrlName' +
                    ' WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 3)');
            lstSearchResults = objSearchResults.get('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        }
```

It returns a result:

```
USER_DEBUG|[72]|DEBUG|(KnowledgeArticleVersion:{Id=ka07F000000a2vvQAA, UrlName=TestTitle, PublishStatus=Online})
```

BUt the SOSL is unable to find the `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object.
The SOSL works fine in real scenario with real data, but does not work with test data.

It never enter this statement.

```
if (!lstSearchResults.isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: Did you execute setfixedsearchresults? In the SOSL docs it tells you what you need to call. It will only return what you set via that method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just as @Eric commented out: You need to place searched object id into Test.setFixedSearchResults

So in your case:

```
Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
fixedSearchResults[0] = objKav.Id;
Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
```

After that you can SOSL objKav.

Reference:

[SOSL Test Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm)